# Angular 7 url routing configuration

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-components, angular-router, angular-component-router

I'm working on an angular 7 application, where I have been facing an interesting issue right now.

My aim is to not using the "hardcoded URLs" throughout in the application.

So, I have an approach like maintaining a single config file where I can have all the site URLs and supplying to the needed components and modules.

Having a configuration like below codes.

routes.ts // Url Configuration File

```
import { LayoutComponent } from './layout/layout.component';
import { AdminIndexComponent } from './admin-index/admin-index.component';
import { AdminRegisterComponent } from './admin-register/admin-register.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';

export class AppRoutes {

    // Angular components url
    public static componentsUrl = {
        base: {
            path: '',
            component: AdminIndexComponent,
            pathMatch: 'full'
        },

        register: {
            path: 'register',
            component: AdminRegisterComponent
        },

        login: {
            path: 'login',
            component: LoginComponent
        },

        home: {
            path: 'home',
            component: LayoutComponent
        }
    };
```

routes-service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutes } from './routes';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class AppRouterService {
  routesArray = [];

  getAppRoutesArray() {
    Object.entries(AppRoutes.componentsUrl).forEach(
        ([key, value]) => this.routesArray.push(value)
    );
    return this.routesArray;
  }
}
```

app-routing.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppRouterService } from './routes-service';

const routes: Routes = ;

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Everything is good at this level. I can able to supply the URL for the routing.

But the interesting case is, I have another component that needs the URL.

admin-index.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RegistrationModule } from 'shared-components';
import { AppRouterService } from '../routes-service'; // Causing the circular dependency

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-index',
  templateUrl: './admin-index.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-index.component.scss']
})
export class AdminIndexComponent implements OnInit {

  appRoutesUrl;
  constructor(private regModule: RegistrationModule, private routerService: AppRouterService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.appRoutesUrl = this.routerService.getAppRoutesObject(); // This variable in binding to component html. So I can retrieve the url from config file
  }
}
```

While I'm doing like this I have got a warning like "*WARNING in Circular dependency detected*". I know the import of "*AdminIndexComponent*" on routes.ts is causing this warning.

May I know how to get rid of this issue? Also please suggest an efficient way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: First, in app-routing.ts, your `const routes: Routes = ;` is incomplete. Second, in admin-index.component.ts, do you need to integrate the component reference into `this.appRoutesUrl` or do you simply need the route name and the path ?

Answer (score 1):

First in app.module.ts, add

```js
import { RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';`
```

Then add this imports,

```js
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
```

After that you can create route like as follows in the same file.

```js
    const appRoutes: Routes = [
      {path: '', component:AdminIndexComponent},
      {path: 'register', component:AdminRegisterComponent},
      {path: 'login', component:LoginComponent},
      {path: 'home', component:LayoutComponent}
    ]
```